# SwiftUI flashScrollIndicators

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiscrollview

In UIKit we have a `UIScrollView` method which allows us to make the scroll indicators flash briefly to inform users there's a scrolling content on screen (which is not always obvious). [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619435-flashscrollindicators):

```
func flashScrollIndicators()
```

> You should call this method whenever you bring the scroll view to
> front.

My question is: how can I get the same on SwiftUI? Take a look at this very silly example, just to show the issue:

If you take a look at this screen you can't know if you can scroll something or not:

[image]

but you actually could:

[image]

How can I make my users aware of scrolling content on SwiftUI?

Comment: Use this library https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of iOS 17.0, there is now:

```
func scrollIndicatorsFlash(onAppear: Bool) -> some View
```

to flash the scroll indicators when the view appears. There's also a version with a trigger parameter that flashes the indicators when a value changes.

Answer (score 1):

Had a hard time with this one on my code base as the deployment target isn't on iOS 17 yet. Luckily I was able to take advantage of the fact that my SwiftUI view was being embedded in a hosting controller by creating a custom subclass.

```
private class ScrollHostingController<Content>: UIHostingController<Content> where Content: View {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        for view in self.view.subviews {
            if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
                scrollView.flashScrollIndicators()
            }
        }
    }
}
```